# How to expand div from bottom to top when there is not enough space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've made a dropdown-like menu a simplified version of which you can see here - [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dnj5hbxx/2/). As you can see I have several of those menus:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="wrapper-main">
  <input class="selected"/>

  <div class="dropdown-wrapper ae-hide">
    <div class="selectable">1</div>
    <div class="selectable">2</div>
    <div class="selectable">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
...
</div>
```

and they actually can be dynamically added to the `DOM` so the count is not fixed. When the height becomes too big a scroll is displayed.

What I want is if when I expand the menu the height of the menu is bigger than the space to the bottom then to render the menu starting from the bottom going up. Another thing that makes it I think, more difficult is that not all menu's will have the same number of `<div>`s (same height).

However I search through the net and couldn't find something helpful.

Comment: So you want the menu to "drop up" instead of down when there is not enough space right. is that it?

Comment: @RamY Sorry, the end of your sentence is a little bit misleading. But I think you got it right. When there is not enough space *bottom* I want the menu to drop up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to check if bottom available height is enought to set dropdown-wrapper's height or not. Update click event as below.

```
     $('body').on('click', '.selected', function (event) {
        $(this).next('.dropdown-wrapper').toggleClass('ae-hide');
        var bottomSpace = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var dropdown = $(this).next('.dropdown-wrapper');
        if ((bottomSpace + $(dropdown).outerHeight()) > $("#container").height()) {
            $(dropdown).css('top', $(dropdown).height() * (-1));
        }
    });
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnj5hbxx/5/)

Note: I have user Outerheight instead of height as outerheight includes padding and border. [Difference between height and outerheight jquery](https://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/jquery-whats-the-difference-between-height-innerheight-and-outerheight)

Comment: Hi. Just two questions - why you prefer `outerHeight()` over `height()` and why those additional 40px in `$(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight(true) + 40;` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extra 40px was my mistake. Sorry for that. Updated answer and fiddle link. Check now.

Comment: Well, to be honest I kinda think that those 40px maybe are not that bad of an idea. I've wrote something similar to your code (that's why I've asked for height() vs outerHeight) and see what comment I left for today: `//TODO maybe adjust a little so it's not pixel perfect.` do you think it's a good idea to add some extra space just for good measure?

Comment: Yes. Good to have some space as there can be padding of container. Additionaly if dropdown height is same as bottomspace then it will render below and dropdown will look like sticking to the bottom. That will be bad UI You can add some additional space like 40px, It wont create any issue.